# Format to display full month of Gregorian dates (wall calendar style) in Arabic or Hebrew

Tags: internationalization, arabic, hebrew, gregorian-calendar, monthcalendar

I'm wondering if, when showing this styling of calendar in a user interface:

[image]

...if the dates should be numbers left to right or, like these writing systems, right to left.

You wouldn't believe how hard it is to Google a sample image of a purely Arabic or purely Hebrew wall calendar!

I finally found ONE Arabic example, and it was numbered right to left.

[image]

I'm guessing I should also do this for Hebrew, but, even when searching using the Hebrew words "לוח שנה קיר ", and setting my Google's search settings to Hebrew language and Israeli locale, all I got was hundreds of examples of mixed English/Hebrew calendars, all numbered left to right.

Does anyone know the answer to this from real-life experience? I'm interested in how **Gregorian** calendars are formatted, not lunisolar religious calendars.

Comment: I’m unsure whether this counts as a programming/coding question.

Comment: @Ole V.V, perhaps it's an odd fit, but StackOverflow is definitely a good place to find people with i18n experience. I got a great answer from Yotam Rosenthal, and would have had a very hard time finding another forum on which to ask such a question, so does the odd fit really bother you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hebrew calendars are right-to-left. You could find some exceptions, but the norm is rtl.
Usually calendars include Hebrew day names, and it would be strange to see them reversed. Also, when the Hebrew dates are included, it uses Hebrew letters for counting, and rtl is natural.
I'm quite sure it's the same in Arabic. The examples in this [google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AA%D9%82%D9%88%D9%8A%D9%85%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B9%D8%B1%D8%A8%D9%8A&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwjRltrNgLX6AhWOHuwKHejrD1YQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AA%D9%82%D9%88%D9%8A%D9%85%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B9%D8%B1%D8%A8%D9%8A&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQDDIFCAAQgAQyBAgAEB4yBAgAEB4yBAgAEB4yBAgAEB4yBAgAEB4yBAgAEB4yBAgAEB4yBAgAEB4yBAgAEB5QAFgAYPwJaABwAHgAgAF6iAF6kgEDMC4xmAEAqgELZ3dzLXdpei1pbWfAAQE&sclient=img&ei=uvAyY9HREY69sAfo17-wBQ&bih=538&biw=1262) support it.